# Git Extract modification in one string line

Tags: bash, git, jenkins, groovy

Any good combination of `Bash` + `git diff` to get in one line the only change that I made in my file?

I'm using form Jenkins DSL, and the best that I get so far is this

```
"${sh(script: "git diff --shortstat", returnStdout: true)}".trim() == "1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)"
```

But what I would love to have is the `"hello world"` text that I just add into one of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got just one hunk,

```
git diff -U0 | sed 1,/^@@/d
```

and strip the leading character off.